# Are we going to get hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

[Winter Bash 2014 is coming up!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats)

Should Mi Yodeya have hats?

The mods didn't seem to pick up on the trend, so i'm posting it for them.

From the MSO post:

> Here's the rundown:
>
> - Hats are enabled on a per-site basis, if we don't want them we can    disable them here
> - Hats are a fun way to end the year, and they are awesome
> - Users can turn off hats on a per-user basis; for those who hate hats you don't have to see everyone else having fun.
> - If we choose to accept, the event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. After the time period, all the hats go
>     away into Last Year's Hat Bin.
> - We need to decide if we want hats by **December 1**
>
> Do we like hats or hate hats?

Comment: We already submitted yes a week ago

Comment: Without community input?

Comment: Yes. Everyone like it the last two times

Comment: On SO too, but that didn't stop them. ;)

Comment: Your asking for opinions is not forbidden. Im just letting you know that theres more to the story than you seem to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As DoubleAA noted in a comment, we already signed Mi Yodeya up for hats.  We aren't required to call for a community vote each year if we're confident of how the community will feel.  Based on past years -- both the positive feedback and the absence of negative feedback -- we just went ahead.  We didn't think anyone would object.  (As noted in the question, any user who doesn't want to see hats can click once on an "I hate hats" link and not be troubled by it again for the year.)

Comment: According to [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161254/266359), it should be noted that the "I hate hats" link will be found on the bottom of every SE page.

Comment: I don't remember where it was last year, nor do I know if it will be in the same place this year.  But if it's not obvious, I trust that somebody will ask about it here on meta.

Comment: Alright, then. I actually don't imagine that anyone would care; IMO hats would be fun (this would be my first Winter Bash), but wouldn't be annoying/irritating, but I guess I'll find out.

Comment: If this is your first, then I encourage you to give it a try. :-)

Comment: Oh, I definitely will <(:^)

Answer (score 8):

## Yes!

Hats are more Jewish than rep or badges - bring them on!

[image: Kippah]

[image: Streimel]

Answer (score -2):

## No

I'm good with my real-life kippa - no need to bring it to the Internet.